# set new link as permalink

Tags: php, permalinks

i have external link stored in a variable `$extlink` which is generated based on different selections in the post.

how do i set the permalink to be this `$extlink`
so that when i click on the post it takes me to the link via program/code

```
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>             

                    <div class="bookindex">

                     <?php the_title();?>

                     <?php 
                        $ext1 = get_field('bookzone');
                        $extlink="http://".$ext1.".com";
                        add_filter( 'post_link', 'external_permalink', 10, 2 ); 
                        function external_permalink( $link, $post )
                        {

                             $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $extlink , TRUE );
                             $url  = esc_url( filter_var( $meta, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) );

                             return $url ? $url : $link;
                        }
                    ?>      

                </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Don't put your `add_filter()` and its associated callback function in The Loop. They should be separate. Also, do you want to filter *every* URL, or only specific ones?

Comment: i want it for all...each and every post created

Answer (score 0):

I would think something is wrong here:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $extlink , TRUE );
```

This is the function:

[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )

You are setting the $extlink as the **$key** parameter, but it is really a meta key? From your explanation, it seems to be a value of the **bookzone** key ...

If the above makes sense, then inside your function, fix the following:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookzone', TRUE );
```

As Pat J said, also remove the **add_filter** and the **function** itself outside the while loop. When you set this particular filter **once**, Wordpress will execute your filter's function whenever the permalink is called inside the Wordpress loop.